# How to Delete particular folder from sharepoint Library using powershell script?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I want to delete particular folders from SharePoint Document library.

I have done this using C#, Its working fine. But I want to modify the same code to powershell.

i tried below code with powershell. I want to modify this C# to Powershell Code I am having doubt in this line:

```
string documentLibraryFolderurl= SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/" + oList + "/" + str + "/" + "Test" + "/" + CategoryName;
if (oWeb.GetFolder(documentLibraryFolderurlAward).Exists == true)
SPFolder folder = oWeb.GetFolder(documentLibraryFolderurlAward);
folder.Delete();
```

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you know the web you want to get... Using SPContext is possible with a bit of munging but in my opinion is not required in most PS scripts. So your PS should look like:

```
#Get the web
$web = Get-SPWeb http://SharePoint/site/web
#Get the list. You don't need the list if you know the list path just pass it as a string instead.
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Documents")
if ($list) {
    #I'm assuming you have the $str and $categoryName vars. It looks much the same if you want:
    $folder = $list.Rootfolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + $str + "/" + "Test" + "/" + $CategoryName
    #or it could simply be:
    $folder = "$($list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)/$str/Test/$CategoryName"
    #Then get the folder:
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folder)
    if ($folder.Exists) {
        $folder.Delete()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell    

$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://thegowtham.sharepoint.com"    

$listname = $web.GetList("http://thegowtham.sharepoint.com /Library")    

function DeleteFiles   
{    
  param($folderUrl)    
  $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)      
  foreach ($file in $folder.Files)   
  {    
    # Delete file by deleting parent SPListItem    
    Write-Host("DELETED FILE: " + $file.name)    
    $list.Items.DeleteItemById($file.Item.Id)    
  }    

}    

# Delete root files    

DeleteFiles($listname.RootFolder.Url)    

# Delete files in folders    

foreach ($folder in $listname.Folders)   
{    
  DeleteFiles($folder.Url)    
}    

# Delete folders    

foreach ($folder in $list.Folders)   
{    
  try   
  {  
    Write-Host("DELETED FOLDER: " + $folder.name)    
    $list.Folders.DeleteItemById($folder.ID)    
  }    
  catch   
  {  
    Write-Host(“Deletion of parent folder already deleted this folder”)    
  }    
}
```

Comment: I want to delete particulae folders using folder names
 if( $spFolder.Name = "Test")
    $splList.Folders.DeleteItemById($spFolder.ID) 

I was running powershell script error is coming "'Name' is a ReadOnly property."

Comment: The correct condition would be if( $spFolder.Name == "Test") (double ==)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the below PnPPowerShell Powershell commands to delete the folder from SharePoint library

```
PS:> Remove-PnPFolder -Name FolderNametobeDelete -Folder "Shared Document/ParentFolder"
```

The PnPPowerShell is available from the below URL, https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell . We have to install PnPPowerShell modules based on the SharePoint version.